# Global registration component in a variable, migration to Vue 3

Tags: migration, vuejs3

I migrating a project to Vue 3. Difficulties encountered, please help.
Have an instances in a helper function, for example:

```js
let VueDevice = new Vue({
  data: {
    isTablet: false,
    isMobile: false,
    isDesktop: false,
  },
//...Methods that calculate screen size});
```

And make it a global variable:

```js
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
...
  device: {
    get() {
      return VueDevice;
    }
  }
});
```

Now I can use data, methods through this variable in any component:

```js
//some component
...
   methods: {
      foo() {
        if(this.device.isMobile) {
            // do something
          }
      },
...
```

How to do the same in Vue 3? What would I be able to use through the variable data of another component and methods in any component of the root component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Vue 3 documentation

> Composition API is now the preferred approach for code reuse
> between components.
> https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins

In this case i think 'Plugins' is what you need https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#introduction

There are 2 more options that you can take a look:

- Provide/inject https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#provide
- Pinia https://pinia.vuejs.org/