# I wonder if mixin function is used in vue3

Tags: vue.js

I wonder if mixin function is used in vue3.
Mixin allows script logic to be imported from other files.
Can composition api use the same function as above?

Comment: RTM: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mixin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888940/global-registration-component-in-a-variable-migration-to-vue-3/72896540#72896540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mixins` are no longer called `mixins` in Composition API ***<sup>1</sup>***.

But it's only the name that has been dropped. Their functionality is, in fact, the bread and butter of this API.

First of all, Composition API allows you to move the entire logic of a component inside its `setup()` function. That's, mostly, what it is all about.
Might not seem that big of a deal at first but, when you think about it, it actually is, as it allows grouping code based on whatever criteria you want, not necessarily by the the type of component member - e.g: (reactive) `data`, `computed`, `methods`, `watch`ers, etc...

Secondly, once a grouping criteria has been defined, the code can be taken out of the component, exported from its own file, and imported into any number of components, using a `useStuff()` function.

These are the new `mixins`: [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html). Quite similar to React hooks.

---

In fairness, I find Composition API a better name than Mixins API.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - technically, that's not true. They [still exist](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mixin) for backwards compatibility, but they're no longer recommended. Composables are the path forward.