# How are components extended using the new Vue 3 <script setup> tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have gone through the Vue docs over and over, and Googled this many times, but I can't find a clear answer on how to accomplish extending components using the Vue 3 `<script setup>` tag.

The old way Vue 2 way would be something like:

```
<script>
import ExtendMe from 'ExtendMe.vue'
export default {
  extends: ExtendMe
}
</script>
```

Using the Vue 3 composition API, it would be something like:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import ExtendMe from 'ExtendMe.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  extends: ExtendMe,
  setup () {
  }
})
</script>
```

But when using the `<script setup>` tag, there doesn't appear to be any clear documentation on this.

All I can find is that it has something to do with provide/inject: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html

However, I can't see in the docs how to tell Vue which component to inject the variables from?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `<script setup>` is available for cases where you don't need anything other than the `setup()` function contents, which means most cases when using Composition API. If you need anything else, you can [use it along the normal script](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script). I personally don't do that. In components where I need anything that's not available in setup script, I just use a normal script and include the `setup()` function in it, returning what it needs to expose to template.

Comment: Great thanks for your input.

So you are saying that, when you need to extend a component, you won't use the `<script setup>` tag, but instead you will use the setup() function for the particular component that needs to extend another component?

Comment: Composition api is used for composition, as the name suggests. You won't gain much from using inheritance with `extends`. "I can't see in the docs how to tell Vue which component to inject the variables from" - they are injected from the nearest parent that has `provide`. Consider explaining your case, this could be XY problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to port some app from Options to Composition. In Options, extending was usied as a typescript friendly substitute for mixins. But in Composition one should no longer need mixins. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905984/i-wonder-if-mixin-function-is-used-in-vue3/72906610#72906610) why. Instead of asking how to extend in `<script setup>`, you should ask yourself why you need it when nobody else does. You can easily achieve the same functionality using composition functions.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes you are correct I am refactoring an Options API app to Composition. I will look into leveraging a Composable to achieve what I need here.